# function overloading - passing constant vs passing variable C++

Tags: c++, overloading

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void somefunc(int a)
{
    cout<<"somefunc1";
}

void somefunc(int &b)
{
    cout<<"somefunc2";
}

int main()
{

    // case 1 
    somefunc(10); // works fine and prints somefunc1

   //case2
    int b=10;
    somefunc(b); // generates compiler error that overloading is ambiguous 

   return 0;
}
```

In `main()` if I pass a constant (say `10`) program compiles and runs and prints `"somefunc1"`, but when I pass a variable (`b` in this case) compiler generates an error that overloading is ambiguous.

I don't understand how is it working internally.
Please help!!

Comment: That's because binding to a reference is an "exact match", so the overloads are ambiguous.

Comment: What you refer to as a *"constant"* is called an *"integer literal"*. Passing a constant (e.g. `const int c = 10;`) would produce a different result. Why passing `c` is different from passing `b` is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @IInspectable: Your constant [would also work fine](http://ideone.com/NbWeSW).

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, of course. A bit sloppy on the wording there. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules for overload resolution are a bit complicated. This is a simplification, applicable to this particular example.

The first step the compiler goes through is finding the "overload set", that is, the set of functions that can be called with the argument. For `somefunc(10)`, only `somefunc(int)` can be called; `somefunc(int&)` cannot be called, because `10`, being a constant, can't be passed by (non-const) reference. So there's only one function in the overload set, and that's the one that gets called.

For `somefunc(b)`, both functions can be called. So the overload set has two functions, `somefunc(int)` and `somefunc(int&)`. Now the compiler has to determine which function is the "best match" for the argument `10`. And the rule is that `int` and `int&` both provide an "exact match", so the rules do not prefer one over the other, and the call is ambiguous.

If the second version of the function had been `somefunc(const int&)` instead of `somefunc(int&)` the call `somefunc(10)` would also be ambiguous.

Comment: If such is the case then overloading should not be allowed for such case.

Comment: @Swapnil: If you want that to happen, you need to work out a paper, and contact the [WG21](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/).

Comment: @Swapnil - which case are you referring to?

Comment: @PeteBecker The main question is "What is the use of function overloading with argument passed by value and reference?" For such cases compiler should throw error and should not wait to get ambiguous error.

Comment: @Swapnil - `somefunc(int)` and `somefunc(int&)` **are** valid, distinguishable overloads. `somefunc(int)` and `somefunc(const int&)` aren't, but consider that they may well be declared in completely separate headers for two completely separate libraries. If you don't call the function, there's no issue.